# How to collect Firebase Messaging statistics

Tags: c#, .net, api, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a mobile project where I am using Firebase Messaging. I need to collect some data on the status of sent messages (received opened, etc.) and show it in our web admin panel. Where can I find information and step-by-step instructions?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [delivery reports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#message-delivery-reports) panel in the Firebase console, and you can export the information to CSV from there. This would be a manual operation though, so probably not ideal if you want to show the data in your own app.

There is also an [API to get aggregated delivery data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#aggregated_delivery_data_via_the_data_api). I'm notsure whether this API can be accessed directly from the client though. If not, you'll have to wrap it in a custom endpoint and call that from your own app.

Finally, if the above don't work for your use-case, you can configure FCM to [export delivery data to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#bigquery-data-export) and build your own reporting API on that.

Comment: yes i think i need  [Export data to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#bigquery-data-export)  and i find that too. but when i try configure my firebase for that something is went wrong. i need step by step tutorial for that. am beginner in firebase

Comment: "something is wrong" is really hard to help with. Since you asked how you can show FCM delivery statistics in your own admin page, I answered that. If you have a problem implementing this, I recommend posting a new question with the [minimal complete code and steps that allow anyone of us to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hey @Gevorg-DavidMelikyan. Any further updates here?